# Extract records from compiled search program, C

Tags: c, database, record, binary-search, brute-force

Does anybody have an idea on how to extract all information from a compiled, record search program?

I think the program works by using a binary search. It was compiled and the database was in the program. The only way to see the records is to make a correct search.

Is there some way that I can bruteforce the program and extract all information?
The record is searched by the ID which starts with 1 and 10 digit long [ 1xxxxxxxxx ].
If you want to try, 1112700303 will work but I don't have the other numbers.

I've tried some Decompiler but I have no idea what I'm doing.

The program can be downloaded from here:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9fwDRGBsrxBT3FiSFdaTnJZcUk/edit

Your help is appreciated as it will increase my knowledge and learn something new here :D

Comment: You will need to reverse engineer the application. This can be an arduous process if the developer went to any lengths to obfuscate the code and/or data format. Decompilers, in general, do not work very well. It is more likely that you will get further using a debugger such as Immunity or IDA Pro. That said, you need a thorough understanding of assembly to do this well and even then, it may not always be obvious.

Comment: Getting the C source of a compiled program is like trying to get the exact cooking recipe for something you got served at a restaurant. You can certainly try to analyze everything on your plate and make a couple of educated guesses, but in the end you can only get a recipe for a meal that looks and tastes pretty similar, yet it would be pure coincidence if it matches the real recipe exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Though question. Is there no way to get hold of the source code (ask the author, search for the program name, ...)?

On Unix/Linux, the program strings extracts printable strings from a binary file. Doing that on x86 executables gives a long list of strings that are just instructions which happen to be ASCII strings, names of functions used by the program, ans other junk. Somewhere it lists initialized text data for the program (printf(3) formats, constant strings used), which in this case shows a bunch of names that look arabic, and some directory names. Perhaps searching for those could help.

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be achieved by using [Snowman](https://derevenets.com/). It might not get the exact source code you are looking for but enough to extract all the data you need such has the constant strings.